# Easy NMinimize does not converge

Tags: warning-messages

I try to minimize the following for a>0:

```
f[a_] := Gamma[3]*a^(-3)*(Integrate[Exp[-u]*(u - a)*1/u, {u, a, Infinity}])^(-1)
```

I put in

```
NMinimize[{f[x],x>0},x]
```

but then he gave me an error that the function might not be bounded at said:

```
NMinimize::cvdiv: Failed to converge to a solution. The function may be unbounded. >>
{-3.18118*10^14, {x -> 1.11822}}
```

Obivously, that is not true. What am I doing wrong?

Cheers

Comment: Do a quick plot, observe, then help `NMinimize` out, e.g. `NMinimize[{f[x], 0 < x < 3}, x]`. You can also try different methods, e.g. `NMinimize[{f[x], 0 < x}, x, Method -> "DifferentialEvolution"]` finds it directly. What version of MM are you on? On 9.0.1, it arrives at answer with no hand-waving...

Comment: I use Mathematica 8, maybe that's the reason why it does not converge...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always start by understanding the behavior of your to be optimized function. When I enter

```
f[a]
```

Mathematica 9 tells me

```
ConditionalExpression[2/(a^3 (E^-a + a ExpIntegralEi[-a])), Im[a] != 0 || Re[a] > 0]
```

So I know it is only defined for positive values of x when the imaginary part is zero.

Use this information in the solution of the optimization problem.

You can either give add a condition that x must be larger than zero as rasher pointed out. (Upper bound 3 is not necessary)

```
NMinimize[{f[x], 0 < x }, x]
```

Or another method that helps is to define a starting point within the admissible range of x values. In this case you could use the function FindMinimum:

```
FindMinimum[f[x], {x, 3}]
```

Both approaches yield:

```
{6.43922, {x -> 2.36388}}
```

For further details please read the documentation: [Numerical Nonlinear Local Optimization](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/ConstrainedOptimizationLocalNumerical.html)